# How to store dictionary in input field (HTML)?

Tags: jquery, html, input, dictionary

I have a big dictionary consisting of multiple fields.

var deal = {'foo':'moo','foo1':'moo1','foo2':'moo2','foo3':'moo3','foo4':'moo4','foo5':'moo5'}

I want to store this as a hidden input field.
i.e.

```
`
<div class="deal">
<input type="hidden" value=deal />//unique for this div
</div>
<div class="deal">
<input type="hidden" value=deal />//unique for this div
</div>
<div class="deal">
<input type="hidden" value=deal />//unique for this div
</div>
```

Retrieving

```
  $(".deal").on('click',function(){
     var deal= $(this).find('input').val();

});
```

And retrieve this using jQuery. While retrieving this by jQuery I am  facing issues i.e. I think the entire data is not being stored.(Half the dictionary is being truncated.)
 Should I instead just query my database and get this? or is there a way to store the dictionary as the input field value ?
If the question is not clear please comment. I will make necessary additions.

Comment: Why are you trying to store it directly on the input instead of just declaring a js variable?

Comment: Because this is unique to every deal object. And there are multiple such objects. And I will be retrieving a dictionary unique to the deal object being clicked.

Comment: Did you tried to serialize and store it and deserialize when needed

Comment: Maybe your dictionary is too long. Browsers can limit length of `value` field.

Comment: Have you tried using a data attribute like: `<div data-deal=" {\"foo\":\"moo\",\"foo\"':\"moo1\",\"foo2\":\"moo2\"}">`

Comment: hmm a small note: you are calling the click event on "deals" but your class is "deal"

Comment: I don't think browsers would truncate input fields, at least not before you reach _very_ unreasonable lengths. Chrome does not have any problem to store at least 16mb in an hidden field.

Comment: I thin you better create an structure on your js code where store all the data related to a name (a dictionary of dictionaries if you want). When an element is clicked you refer to the element of the dictionary that matches with the name of the element clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could store your data in Javascript and have reference on your HTML elements to those JS vars? Like:

```
var dict1 = {name:"val", name2:"val"};
<div class="deal" data-dict="dict1"></div>
```

And then just bind it like this:

```
$(".deal").on('click',function(){
    var dictName = $(this).data('dict'),
        deal = window[dictName];
});
```